# Under what Conditions two different objects may have same hashcode() value..?

Tags: java, hashcode

What I know is:-

"`int hashCode()` returns the memory address of the object as
the default hash value of the object."

If the references `x` and `y` denote two different objects, the expression
`(x.hashCode() == y.hashCode())` is not always false

So, I want to ask in which cases the hash values of 2 different objects are same.

Comment: It totally depends on the hasCode() implementation of the class.

Comment: I can assume those were not overloaded?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16418737/4028085

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917731/does-hashcode-return-the-memory-address

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17481407/4028085

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15978077/928952

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does hashcode number represent the memory address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418713/does-hashcode-number-represent-the-memory-address)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override `hashCode` in your classes. You would usually override it along with overriding `equals`, so that if `a.equals(b)` is true, `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` is also true (even if `(a == b)` is false).

However, even if `a.equals(b)` is false, `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` may still be true.

As you can see in the Javadoc of Object class :

> - If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must
>     produce the same integer result.
> - **It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the
>     hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct
>     integer results**. However, the programmer should be aware that
>     producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the
>     performance of hashtables.

Comment: @Hiru equals method will only check for hashCode if you implement it this way. I don't see any reason to implement it this way though.

Comment: @Hiru yes, but the default implementation of equals doesn't check hashCode, it just checks if a == b.

Answer (score 1):

HashCode doesn't *always* return the memory address (which itself may be bogus since objects may be relocated in memory). A class that provides its own `hashCode` might have an algorithm that causes collisions (two different objects with the same hashCode).

Additionally, you can get `equals` involved: Two objects, where `a!=b` but `a.equals(b)` is true, **must** have the same hashCode or certain data structures like hashmaps, hashsets, LRU caches, etc, will not work properly.
However, if two objects that are not equal have the same hashCode, this poses no problem--`hashCode` is used in many cases as a hint for performance improvement (e.g. in hashMap). While poor hashCode implementations such as `return 1;` will not cause failure of a properly-written data structure, they will cause performance to drop (e.g. in the case of a HashMap, amortized O(1) becomes O(N)).

Thirdly, even the best hashCode will necessarily have collisions if there are more than 4,294,967,296 different objects of that class. This is because there are only 4,294,967,296 distict hashCode values possible because hashCode is an int, and by pigeonhole princple.

Contract for `Object#hashCode()` and all overriding implementations:

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
>
> It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hashtables.

Answer (score 0):

The "return memory address" implementation of `hashCode` is the *default*. Almost always, when you're using a type of object in a HashMap or HashSet or what-have-you, you'll *override* `hashCode` with your own implementation, which could have nothing at all to do with the memory address of the object.